# Reduce method complexity by removing foreach loops

Tags: c#, linq, cyclomatic-complexity

I have the following code in c#:

```
foreach (var c1 in object1.Collection1)
{
    foreach (var c2 in c1.Collection2.Where(b => b.Settings?.Name != null))
    {
        foreach (var c3 in c2.Settings.Name.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).Select(s => s.ToLowerInvariant().GetHashCode()).ToList())
        {
            //process c3
        }
    }
}
```

How to use `linq` to combine the elements I need (`c2.Settings.Name`) in one array and have only one `foreach` because with this code, my method complexity is 5 and `Sonar` is complaining about this.

Comment: You could certainly use LINQ, but you likely won't end up with something that's any more efficient and it *might* be less readable.

Comment: @MattBurland and what would you choose in this situation?

Comment: It´s a popular mistake that using LINQ makes your code any better in consideration to performance or complexity. Actually it just *hides* the complexity away which is often not a good thing. Linq will also iterate the items in your collection exactly the same way you would do this with any loop-based approach. Leave the code as it is, it´s easy to understand and gets your things done, doesn´t it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var query= Collection1.SelectMany(c1=>c1.Collection2
                                        .Where(b => b.Settings?.Name != null)
                                        .SelectMany(c2=>c2.Settings.Name
                                        .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
                                        .Select(s => s.ToLowerInvariant().GetHashCode())));
```

Or using several `from` in linq query notation:

```
var query = from c1 in Collection1
            from c2 in c1.Collection2.Where(b => b.Settings?.Name != null)
            from c3 in c2.Settings.Name.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
                                       .Select(s => s.ToLowerInvariant().GetHashCode())
            select c3;
```

Comment: and how the code would look with selectMany?

Comment: Here it is, but as you can see is less readable than using query notation

Comment: I'm not sure that either of these actually improves on readability or complexity from the OP's original code, but it does answer the question.  +1